# How to create a post with a poll in Chatter via Apex?

Tags: chatter

Hi I'm using ConnectApiHelper to create a post with mention to a user. 
postFeedElement(communityId, feedElement, feedElementFileUpload)

But how do I attach a poll at the same time?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to add a high level code example using the ConnectApi:

```
ConnectApi.PollCapabilityInput myPoll = new ConnectApi.PollCapabilityInput();
myPoll.choices = new List<String>{'a','b','c'};

ConnectApi.FeedElementCapabilitiesInput itemCapabilities = new ConnectApi.FeedElementCapabilitiesInput();
itemCapabilities.poll = myPoll;

ConnectApi.FeedItemInput feedItem = new ConnectApi.FeedItemInput();

feedItem.feedElementType = ConnectApi.FeedElementType.FeedItem;
feedItem.capabilities = itemCapabilities;
feedItem.subjectId = sfId; //This can be any Salesforce Id that has Chatter enabled for it

ConnectApi.MessageBodyInput messageBodyInput = new ConnectApi.MessageBodyInput();

messageBodyInput.messageSegments = new List<ConnectApi.MessageSegmentInput>();

ConnectApi.TextSegmentInput textSegment = new ConnectApi.TextSegmentInput();
textSegment.text = 'What choice do you want?';
messageBodyInput.messageSegments.add(textSegment);

feedItem.body = messageBodyInput;

ConnectApi.FeedElement feedElement = ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.postFeedElement(null,feedItem);
```

Answer (score 0):

The [ConnectApiHelper](https://github.com/alouie-sfdc/ConnectApiHelper) class currently doesn't support taking a [ConnectApi.​FeedElementCapabilitiesInput](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_connectapi_input_feed_element_capabilities.htm#apex_connectapi_input_feed_element_capabilitites) as a parameter when posting a feed item. You'd need that in order to use a [ConnectApi.​PollCapabilityInput](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_connectapi_input_poll_capability.htm#apex_connectapi_input_poll_capability). You'll need to either avoid using ConnectApiHelper, or modify your copy of it so that it takes in the additional parameter.

Note: I'm the author of the ConnectApiHelper class and I'll update it to take in the capabilities input when I have the time. I'll also add support for the "visibility" parameter, which I've also gotten a request for. Will update this thread when it's done.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I'm modifying postFeedItemWithMentions in ConnectApiHelper to take in additional parameter. But ​PollCapabilityInput pollInput = new ConnectApi.​PollCapabilityInput(); does not compile. It says Error: Compile Error: Invalid type: ConnectApi.​PollCapabilityInput. If you just put in line in a new Apex class with version 34, you will see that it does not compile. Any help on this will be highly appreciated!

Comment: This line fails compile: ConnectApi.​PollCapabilityInput pollInput = new ConnectApi.​PollCapabilityInput();

Comment: There was an invalid hidden character in the line. Once fixed, it compiles fine.

Comment: I've seen that when copying and pasting from the API documentation sometimes. It's very annoying.